# Java applet freezes whenever I go back to intro screen of my game

Tags: java, swing, applet, freeze

I'm trying to create a java applet which lets a user play the 20 questions game, however when a game has ended and I click on replay the game, it freezes when it's supposed to go back to the intro screen. I've presented my code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;




//json classes
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;




//google classes
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;

public class Interface extends JPanel implements ActionListener, PropertyChangeListener{
    //removes serialization warning
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**Instances for the Buttons**/
    private JButton noButton;
    private JButton yesButton;
    private JButton unsureButton;
    private JButton replayButton;
    private JButton newGame;
    private JButton addQuestion; 
    /**Instances for the text used**/
    private JLabel questionLabel;
    /**Instances for the dialog boxes**/
    private JDialog addQuestionDialog;
    private JOptionPane addQuestionPane;
    private JDialog nameDialog;
    private JOptionPane namePane;
    /**Instances for the textfields**/
    private TextField questionTextField;
    private TextField mqlYesTextField;
    private TextField mqlNoTextField;
    private TextField nameTextField;
    /**Instance for keeping track of game state**/
    private boolean isGameOver = false;
    /**keeps track of the current and previous questions**/
    private int currentQuestionId = 1, previousQuestionId = 1;
    /**Instances of Arraylist**/
    private ArrayList<Integer> alreadyAskedQuestions;
    private ArrayList<Integer> columnValues;
    /**number of questions asked to the user so far**/;
    private int questionsAsked = 1;
    private JSONArray mqlResults = null;

    private Model sqlModel;
    private String mqlQuery = "[{\"name\":null, \"limit\":5";

    /**Constructor**/
    public Interface(){
        super();
        sqlModel = new Model();

        questionTextField = new TextField(50);
        mqlYesTextField = new TextField(100);
        mqlNoTextField = new TextField(100);

        alreadyAskedQuestions = new ArrayList<Integer>(21);
        columnValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(21);
        initGUI();
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        removeAll();

        JLabel introLabel = createIntroLabel();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(introLabel,c);
        GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();
        d.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        d.ipady = 200;
        d.gridx = 0;
        d.gridy = 1;
        d.weighty = 0.5;
        add(createMainPanel(),d);
    }

    public JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

        JPanel recentSearchesPanel = new JPanel();
        recentSearchesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
        recentSearchesPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        //create Recent searches text
        JLabel recentSearchText = new JLabel("Recent searches:");
        recentSearchText.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        recentSearchText.setFont(new Font("Gabriola",Font.BOLD,30));
        //add text into Panel
        recentSearchesPanel.add(recentSearchText);
        ArrayList<String> recentSearches = sqlModel.getRecentSearches();
        for(int i=0; i<recentSearches.size(); i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(recentSearches.get(i));
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            label.setFont(new Font("Gabriola",Font.BOLD,30));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            recentSearchesPanel.add(label);
        }
        //add recent searches in the leftmost column of the main panel
        mainPanel.add(recentSearchesPanel);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        newGame = new JButton(new ImageIcon("src\\Icons\\icon_play_en.png"));
        newGame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        newGame.setOpaque(true);
        newGame.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(newGame);
        GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();
        d.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        d.gridy = 1;
        addQuestion = new JButton(new ImageIcon("src\\Icons\\icon_addQuestion.png"));
        addQuestion.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addQuestion.setOpaque(true);
        addQuestion.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(addQuestion,d);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        JPanel popularSearchesPanel = new JPanel();
        popularSearchesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
        popularSearchesPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JLabel popularSeachText = new JLabel("Popular searches:");
        popularSeachText.setFont(new Font("Gabriola",Font.BOLD,30));
        popularSeachText.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        popularSearchesPanel.add(popularSeachText);

        ArrayList<String> popularSearches = sqlModel.getPopularSearches();
        for(int i=0; i<popularSearches.size(); i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(popularSearches.get(i));
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            label.setFont(new Font("Gabriola",Font.BOLD,30));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            recentSearchesPanel.add(label);
        }
        mainPanel.add(popularSearchesPanel);

        return mainPanel;
    }

    /**The initGUI method will create the GUI and hold all its components**/
    public void gameGUI(){
        //the layout is a new BorderLayout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

        //clear all components currently in panel
        removeAll();

        add(createIntroLabel());
        mqlResults = getMQLData(mqlQuery + "}]");
        //are we in game over state
        isGameOver = ((mqlResults != null) && ( (mqlResults.size() <= 1) || (questionsAsked == 20) ));

        add(createQuestionsPanel(isGameOver));
        add(createGuessedPanel());
        add(createAnswerButtonPanel());
        //calling revalidate, avoids an error of the programme freezing
        revalidate();
    }

    /**Create a panel which holds the labels and the button that will change the labels color **/
    private JLabel createIntroLabel()
    {   
        JLabel introLabel = new JLabel("Twenty Questions");
        introLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        introLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        introLabel.setFont(new Font("Forte",Font.BOLD,108));
        introLabel.setOpaque(true);
        return introLabel;
    }

    /**The createQuestions method will display the current question at the time**/
    private JPanel createQuestionsPanel(boolean gameOver){
        //Create a new panel
        JPanel questionPanel = new JPanel();
        questionPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        questionPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        if(gameOver) {
            if(mqlResults.size() > 0)
                questionLabel = new JLabel("is your Character: "+((JSONObject)mqlResults.get(0)).get("name") );
            else //noone was found
                questionLabel = new JLabel("couldn't find any matches :(");

            //addQuestion();
        }
        else
            questionLabel = new JLabel("Q"+questionsAsked+": "+sqlModel.getData("questionid","questionid = "+currentQuestionId, 2));

        //make the label centred
        questionLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        //the Foreground is white
        questionLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        questionLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.PLAIN,30));
        //add Label to the panel
        questionPanel.add(questionLabel);

        //return questionPanel
        return questionPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createGuessedPanel() {
        JPanel guessedPanel = new JPanel();
        guessedPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
        guessedPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        System.out.println(mqlQuery);

        if((questionsAsked > 1) && (mqlResults.size() > 0)) {
            for (Object result : mqlResults) {
                JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel((String)((JSONObject)result).get("name"));
                resultLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                resultLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                resultLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.PLAIN,30));
                guessedPanel.add(resultLabel);
            }
        }
        return guessedPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createAnswerButtonPanel()
    {
        JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel();
        answerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

        //MQL query couldn't find any results
        if ( (mqlResults != null) && (mqlResults.size() == 0) ) {
            replayButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/replay_icon.png")));
            replayButton.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            replayButton.setOpaque(true);
            replayButton.addActionListener(this);
            answerPanel.add(replayButton);
        }

        else {
            //the no button will be added to the panel
            noButton = new JButton("NO");
            noButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
            noButton.setOpaque(true);
            Font noFont = new Font("Bauhaus 93",Font.BOLD,30);
            noButton.setFont(noFont);
            noButton.addActionListener(this);
            answerPanel.add(noButton);

            //if the initial question has already been asked, create an unsure button
            if( (questionsAsked > 1) && !isGameOver )
            {
                unsureButton = new JButton("UNSURE");
                unsureButton.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                unsureButton.setOpaque(true);
                Font maybeFont = new Font("Bauhaus 93",Font.BOLD,30);
                unsureButton.setFont(maybeFont);
                unsureButton.addActionListener(this);
                answerPanel.add(unsureButton);
            }

            //the yes button will be added to the panel             
            yesButton = new JButton("YES");
            Font yesFont = new Font("Bauhaus 93",Font.BOLD,30);
            yesButton.setFont(yesFont);
            yesButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            yesButton.setOpaque(true);
            yesButton.addActionListener(this);
            answerPanel.add(yesButton);
            //return answerPanel
        }
        return answerPanel; 
    }

    private int getNextQuestionId(int previousQuestionId) {
        int result;
        while(true) {
            double random = Math.random();
            result = sqlModel.chooseQuestion(previousQuestionId, random);
            //if question selected has already been asked in this game session
            System.out.println(alreadyAskedQuestions);

            if(alreadyAskedQuestions.contains(result)) {
                /*int value = Integer.parseInt(sqlModel.getData("questionvalues", "questionid = "+result, previousQuestionId + 1));
                if(value>=5) {
                    value = value - 5;
                    //change value in (result, previousQuestionId) cell
                    sqlModel.updateEntry("questionvalues", "`"+previousQuestionId+"` = "+value, "questionid = "+result);
                    int previousTotal = Integer.parseInt(sqlModel.getData("questionvalues", "questionid = 5000", previousQuestionId+1));
                    int newTotal = previousTotal - 5;
                    //decrement total value by 5, in the previousQuestionId column
                    sqlModel.updateEntry("questionvalues", "`"+previousQuestionId+"` = "+newTotal, "questionid = 5000");
                }*/
            }
            else
                return result;
        }
    }

    private JSONArray getMQLData(String query) {
        JSONArray results = null;
        try {
              HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
              HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();
              JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
              GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread");
              url.put("query", query);
              url.put("key", "AIzaSyAA0uodQOasgTIaGRHUeoKwnfS-FVoDxJc");
              HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
              HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
              JSONObject response = (JSONObject)parser.parse(httpResponse.parseAsString());
              results = (JSONArray)response.get("result");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }

    private void addQuestion() {
        questionTextField = new TextField(50);

        Object[] componentsArray = {"Question:", questionTextField, "MQLYes:", mqlYesTextField, "MQLNo:", mqlNoTextField};
        Object[] options = {"Enter", "Cancel"};
        addQuestionDialog = new JDialog(new JFrame(),"Add question");
        addQuestionPane = new JOptionPane(componentsArray, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, options, options[0]);

        int x = getX() + getWidth()/2, y = getY() + getHeight()/2;

        addQuestionDialog.setContentPane(addQuestionPane);
        addQuestionDialog.setResizable(false);
        addQuestionDialog.setSize(300,210);
        addQuestionDialog.setVisible(true);
        addQuestionDialog.setLocation(x, y);
        addQuestionDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

        addQuestionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }

    /** This method reacts to state changes in the option pane. */
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        String prop = e.getPropertyName();

        if (addQuestionDialog.isVisible() && (e.getSource() == addQuestionPane) && (JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop) || JOptionPane.INPUT_VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop))) {
            Object value = addQuestionPane.getValue();

            if (value == JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
                //ignore reset
                return;
            }

            //Reset the JOptionPane's value.
            //If you don't do this, then if the user
            //presses the same button next time, no
            //property change event will be fired.
            addQuestionPane.setValue(
                JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);

            if (value.equals("Enter")) {
                String questionTypedText = questionTextField.getText();
                String mqlYesTypedText = mqlYesTextField.getText();
                String mqlNoTypedText = mqlNoTextField.getText();

                sqlModel.addQuestion(questionTypedText, mqlYesTypedText, mqlNoTypedText);
                questionTextField.setText("");
                mqlYesTextField.setText("");
                mqlNoTextField.setText("");
            } else { //user closed dialog or clicked cancel
                addQuestionDialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        else if (nameDialog.isVisible() && (e.getSource() == namePane) && (JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop) || JOptionPane.INPUT_VALUE_PROPERTY.equals(prop))) {
            Object value = namePane.getValue();

            if (value == JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
                //ignore reset
                return;
            }

            namePane.setValue(
                JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE);

            if (value.equals("Enter")) {
                sqlModel.addCelebrity(alreadyAskedQuestions, columnValues, nameTextField.getText());
            }
            //else, user clicked cancel, in either case, close the Dialog box
            nameDialog.setVisible(false);
            mqlQuery = "[{\"name\":null, \"limit\":5";
            isGameOver = false;
            initGUI();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(newGame)) {
            gameGUI();
        }

        else if(e.getSource().equals(addQuestion)) {
            addQuestion();
        }

        //if you press the no button
        else if (e.getSource().equals(noButton)) {
            if(!isGameOver) {
                //don't update questionvalues for this case
                alreadyAskedQuestions.add(currentQuestionId);
                columnValues.add(-1);

                //update MQLQuery
                String s = sqlModel.getData("questionid", "questionid = "+currentQuestionId, 4);
                if( (questionsAsked > 1) && !s.equals("") )
                    mqlQuery = mqlQuery + ", \"ms"+questionsAsked+":"+s;
                else
                    mqlQuery = mqlQuery + s;

                currentQuestionId = getNextQuestionId(previousQuestionId);
                questionsAsked++;
                gameGUI();
            }
            else {
                //create new JOptionPane asking for celebrity name
                nameTextField = new TextField(50);

                Object[] componentsArray = {"Please enter your characters name:", questionTextField};
                Object[] options = {"Enter", "Cancel"};
                nameDialog = new JDialog();
                namePane = new JOptionPane(componentsArray, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, options, options[0]);

                int x = getX() + getWidth()/2, y = getY() + getHeight()/2;

                nameDialog.setContentPane(namePane);
                nameDialog.setResizable(false);
                nameDialog.setSize(300,210);
                nameDialog.setVisible(true);
                nameDialog.setLocation(x, y);
                nameDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

                addQuestionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
            }
        }

        //if you pressed the yes button
        else if (e.getSource().equals(yesButton)) {
            if(isGameOver) {
                String name = ""+((JSONObject)mqlResults.get(0)).get("name");
                sqlModel.addCelebrity(alreadyAskedQuestions, columnValues, name);
                mqlQuery = "[{\"name\":null, \"limit\":5";
                isGameOver = false;
                initGUI();
            }
            else {
                //update the value in the questionValues table
                if(previousQuestionId != currentQuestionId) {
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(sqlModel.getData("questionvalues", "questionid = "+currentQuestionId, previousQuestionId + 1));
                    value += 5;
                    //back ticks around previousQuestionId, so SQL compiler knows it's a column name
                    //change value in (currentQuestionId, previousQuestionId) cell
                    sqlModel.updateEntry("questionvalues", "`"+previousQuestionId+"` = "+value, "questionid = "+currentQuestionId);
                    int previousTotal = Integer.parseInt(sqlModel.getData("questionvalues", "questionid = 5000", previousQuestionId+1));
                    int newTotal = previousTotal + 5;
                    //decrement total value by 5, in the previousQuestionId column
                    sqlModel.updateEntry("questionvalues", "`"+previousQuestionId+"` = "+newTotal, "questionid = 5000");
                }
                alreadyAskedQuestions.add(currentQuestionId);
                columnValues.add(1);
                //update MQLQuery
                String s = sqlModel.getData("questionid", "questionid = "+currentQuestionId, 3);
                if(questionsAsked > 1)
                    mqlQuery = mqlQuery + ", \"ms"+questionsAsked+":"+s;
                else
                    mqlQuery = mqlQuery + s;

                if (questionsAsked > 1)
                    previousQuestionId = currentQuestionId;
                currentQuestionId = getNextQuestionId(previousQuestionId);

                questionsAsked++;
                gameGUI();
            }
        }

        //if you pressed the unsure button
        else if (e.getSource().equals(unsureButton)) {
            //update the value in the questionValues table
            if(previousQuestionId != currentQuestionId) {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(sqlModel.getData("questionvalues", "questionid = "+currentQuestionId, previousQuestionId + 1));
                if(value >= 5) {
                    value -= 5;
                    //back ticks around previousQuestionId, so SQL compiler knows it's a column name
                    sqlModel.updateEntry("questionvalues", "`"+previousQuestionId+"` = "+value, "questionid = "+currentQuestionId);
                    //change value in (result, previousQuestionId) cell
                    sqlModel.updateEntry("questionvalues", "`"+previousQuestionId+"` = "+value, "questionid = "+currentQuestionId);
                    int previousTotal = Integer.parseInt(sqlModel.getData("questionvalues", "questionid = 5000", previousQuestionId+1));
                    int newTotal = previousTotal - 5;
                    //decrement total value by 5, in the previousQuestionId column
                    sqlModel.updateEntry("questionvalues", "`"+previousQuestionId+"` = "+newTotal, "questionid = 5000");
                }
            }
            alreadyAskedQuestions.add(currentQuestionId);
            columnValues.add(0);

            if (questionsAsked > 1)
                previousQuestionId = currentQuestionId;
            currentQuestionId = getNextQuestionId(previousQuestionId);
            questionsAsked++;
            gameGUI();
        }

        else if(e.getSource().equals(replayButton)) {
            mqlQuery = "[{\"name\":null, \"limit\":5";
            isGameOver = false;
            initGUI();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
When it's game over, the user is presented with the following screen, however clicking replay freezes the applet, when all it really does is call the initGUI method, which runs perfectly fine when the applet first starts. I've added a print statement at the end of the initGUI method and it shows up in my console when I click on replay, so the code successfully goes through the initGUI method, however it doesn't change the appearance of the applet.

Comment: This `new ImageIcon("src\\Icons\\replay_icon.png")` is going to be a problem, you should never reference `src` directly, the path will no longer exist after the program is built.  Use something more like `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/replay_icon.png"))`.  Also, where's the `actionPerformed` method? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I'm receiving a nullpointerexception when I substitute in ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/replay_icon.png")). But the file does exist!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my problem, apparently calling revalidate() at the end of my GUI methods is a must, else the screen doesn't update, even though the JFrame is successfully adding new components.